# Ulogin redirect на себя же

Tags: всплывающее-окно, ulogin, авторизация

Добрый день. Мучаюсь уже довольно долго...ВСе перепробовал. Ничего не помогает.
Задача: После авторизации - возвращаться на ту же самую страницу, откуда был сделан вход.
Проблема: Авторизация сделана с помощью модального окна на css:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="enter" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<p><a href="#login"><input type="button" value="ВОЙТИ ЧЕРЕЗ СОЦ. СЕТИ" id="button"/></a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="login" class="reg">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<p>Через какой сайт Вы бы хотели авторизоваться на нашем сайте?</p>

<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Итак. У нас есть кнопка Войти через соц. сети - которая открывается как модальное окно:
адрес данной кнопки: table/страница_откуда_делаем_вход#login

Также есть файл check.php, который проверяет авторизацию с помощью сервиса ulogin:

```
<?php session_start();

   $page=$_GET[page];
   $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $user = json_decode($s, true);
   //$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
   //$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц.  сети
   //$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
   //$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя

   if (isset($user)) 
            {

   $_SESSION['user'] = $user; 
   header("Location: http://$page");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Авторизация проходит. НО после всех наших манипуляций мы возвращаемся на вот эту страницу: table/страница_откуда_делаем_вход.php#login

Нужно - чтобы переход был на страницу: table/страница_откуда_делаем_вход.php
Иначе нас как бы снова просят авторизоваться через соц. сети.
P.S. Если закрыть данное окно авторизации и обновить страницу - видно - что мы авторизованы.

Как сделать чтобы все возвращалось именно на страницу откуда делали вход, а не на модальное окно.

Спасибо!

Comment: Во первых у тебя не закрыта двойная кавычка. А потом мне кажется, что хеш подставляется через js.

Comment: Есть разница?)

    <div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="...redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page=<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"></div>

Comment: @Nabla ну в файле check.php убери редирект, добавь var_dump($page) и смотри, куда ведет ссылка.

Comment: я тоже думаю что в js хештег ставится ибо это клиентская фича, php не хранит это в REQUEST_URI

Comment: Вот куда))

string(0) ""

Comment: @Nabla поправь для начала всё-таки кавычки.

Comment: Поправил давно уже:
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page=<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"></div>

$_SESSION['user'] = $user; 
   var_dump($page);
   exit;

Comment: зачем там в редиректе стоял header("Location: http://$page");
http://  

если ты передаешь $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Говорил, еще надо делать urlencode.

$page=$_GET[page]; почему тут нет кавычек? Это константа ?

Comment: $page=$_GET['page']; - поставил кавычки. тоже самое. string(0) ""
Сделал вот так: redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php=<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
Написал терь NULL

Comment: Так а что в адресной строке? string(0) никак не может быть такого. Урлэнкод туда

http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?> 

Знак вопроса не надо энкодить? остальное ж энкодится. %3F вместо ?

http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php%3Fpage=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>

Comment: Отлично) ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!)
Оформи плиз в виде ответа. Мало ли - кому пригодится?
1) Там где код html - написал как ты. Действительно энкодировать надо.
2) Там где Check.php - все-таки нужно оставить $page=$_GET['page']; и header("Location: http://$page"); - иначе не получается редиректа. Останавливается все на http://table/check.php?page=

P.S. Без urlencode тоже все работает. ))))
Не знаю как) Но щас работает все без urlencode)))

Comment: Так оно не может без урлэнкод работать так как urlencode он и преобразовывает значки эти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо делать urlencode redirect_uri:

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php%3Fpage%3D<?php echo  urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
```

Comment: Без urlencode работает. Не знаю как. но работает)

Comment: Ну потому что там знаков, наверное, кроме слеша нет, а возьми другую страницу и сломается.
Надо urlencode! :D